# Best DOMContentLoaded fallback

Tags: javascript

What is the best way for fallback of DOMContentLoaded that is not supported by < IE9?

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){/*code here*/})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/DOMContentLoaded):

> Internet Explorer 8 supports the `readystatechange` event, which can be
>   used to detect that the DOM is ready. In earlier version of Internet
>   Explorer, this state can be detected by regularily trying to execute
>   `document.documentElement.doScroll("left")`, as this snippet will throw
>   an error until the DOM is ready.

Comment: Nobody uses that anymore. Don't worry about it.

Comment: Thank you, can you could add a solution to the question inline to use this method as a callback if not ask too much?

Comment: There are 2 scripts on the MDN: https://github.com/addyosmani/jquery.parts/blob/master/jquery.documentReady.js, https://github.com/dperini/ContentLoaded/blob/master/src/contentloaded.js